# Delete Everything After a Special Character

Tags: php, regex

I am new to regex, and I think this is my best solution. I am trying to find away to remove all text after a special character is found.

At the moment I am playing with

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $word);
```

But as you probably know, that only removes all special charters, not everything after the first special character is found.

Comment: Every character is special in its own way.

Comment: Are `a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()%&-` the special characters? Or is it any character different from them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove every character starting from the first character different from `a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()%&-`, you can use the following:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-].*/s', '', $word);
```

If instead, you want to remove every thing after a character from `a-zA-Z0-9_ %[].()%&-` is found, you can use the following:

```
preg_replace('/[a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-].*/s', '', $word);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn it around and use [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', $word, $matches);
```

`$matches[0]` will contain the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
$word = "Overflow's";

preg_match('/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/', $word, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

Which returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Overflow
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index of the first occurrence of the  special character with [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and then use [substr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php).